# OnUpdate() not calling the widget service

Tags: android, listview, android-widget, android-syncadapter

i am developing a widget for my app. Widget name is history, when user browses any URL i will store it in local db, which widget listing from it.

when i open the widget, it fetches all the details from the local db and showing it in widget's list-view.

1) when i open the widget, first onUpdate method of **WidgetProvider** is called

2) then onUpdate() will call the service **WidgetService**

3) then service will call the **Widget Factory** to update the list-view using locally stored db.

In widget factory it will get the db values and update the lisviews in widget.

**the above is the process happening when setting up the widget.**

**The first class:**

```
        public class WidgetProviderFavorite extends AppWidgetProvider {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
          public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {            
            for (int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
              Intent svcIntent=new Intent(ctxt, WidgetServiceFavorite.class);
              svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
              svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));  
              RemoteViews widget=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_favorite);
              widget.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.listFavoriteLogin,svcIntent);                                  
              Intent clickIntent=new Intent(ctxt, WidgetActivityFavorite.class);                                 
              PendingIntent clickPI=PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0,clickIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

              widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listFavoriteLogin, clickPI);                                              
              appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);

            }

            super.onUpdate(ctxt, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
          }
```

**The second class:**

```
        public class WidgetServiceFavorite extends RemoteViewsService {
          @Override
          public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

            return(new WidgetFactoryFavorite(this.getApplicationContext(),intent));         
          }
        }
```

**The third class:** which is going to fetch and update the listview.

fetching done in construtor and getViewAt() (Its called automatically) will be setting the values.

```
        public class WidgetFactoryFavorite extends Activity implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

          public WidgetFactoryFavorite(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
              int array_Index=0;
              int array_Length=0;
              WidgetDatabase db1=new WidgetDatabase(ctxt);
              List<WidgetDatabaseModel> facorite = db1.getFavorite();
              array_Length=facorite.size(); 

              mNames=new String[array_Length];                                     
              mSummary=new String[array_Length];

              for (WidgetDatabaseModel cn : facorite) {                     
                  mNames[array_Index] =cn.getNAME(); 
                  mSummary[array_Index]= cn.getSUMMARY();
                  array_Index++;
              } 

              this.mCtxt=ctxt;
              intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                                              AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

          }
            @Override
          public void onCreate() {
            // no-op
          }

          @Override
          public void onDestroy() {
            // no-op
          }

          @Override
          public int getCount() {
            return(mNames.length);
          }

          @Override
          public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

              RemoteViews row=new RemoteViews(mCtxt.getPackageName(),
                                             R.layout.widget_rowfavorite);

              row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, mNames[position]);

              Intent i=new Intent();
              Bundle extras=new Bundle(); 
              extras.putString(WidgetProviderFavorite.sExtra_Guid, mGuid[position]);
              extras.putString(WidgetProviderFavorite.sExtra_Url, mUrl[position]);
              i.putExtras(extras);
              row.setOnClickFillInIntent(android.R.id.text1, i);

              return(row);
          }

          @Override
          public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
            return(null);
          }

          @Override
          public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return(1);
          }

          @Override
          public long getItemId(int position) {
            return(position);
          }

          @Override
          public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return(true);
          }

          @Override
          public void onDataSetChanged() {
          }
        }
```

**My Problem is:**

**Its not syncing side by by side when i browse some URL in my browser**. i have used the below code sync when database is updated by new URL.

```
        int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(mActivity).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(mActivity, WidgetProviderFavorite.class));
        WidgetProviderFavorite myWidget = new WidgetProviderFavorite();
        myWidget.onUpdate(mActivity, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(mActivity),ids);
```

its calling the onUpdate method(). but onUpdate doesn't call the service class which is going to call factory class and upadting the lisview with new database values. the flow i mentioned earlier was not happening when new values added to db.

why service method is not called?

or any other method refresh the list-view when database values changes

Comment: Can anyone please give me some suggestion. i am really stuck from last week... not able to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my self:

We have to call notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged() in onUpdateMethod().

```
   appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.listView);
```

Complete OnUpdate():

```
    public class WidgetProviderFavorite extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {            
        for (int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
          Intent svcIntent=new Intent(ctxt, WidgetServiceFavorite.class);
          svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
          svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));  
          RemoteViews widget=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_favorite);
          widget.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.listFavoriteLogin,svcIntent);                                  
          Intent clickIntent=new Intent(ctxt, WidgetActivityFavorite.class);                                 
          PendingIntent clickPI=PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0,clickIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

          widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listFavoriteLogin, clickPI); 

          appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.listView);                

          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);

        }

        super.onUpdate(ctxt, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
      }
```

Comment: in my side onUpdate calling but service on listview is service part is not calling although  I call notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged

Comment: You saved my day!